# Can anyone tell me why Worksheet().Activate does not work which leads to automating the creation of Pivot Tables?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have written a vba code which automatically creates a pivot table when I press a button.

It has worked out pretty good for several times. But after 1 time it stopped working and it says **Run Time Error 424**.

It seems something is wrong with the `Worksheet().activate` function.

But I do not get it since the spreadsheet is exactly called the same as in the function and why wouldn't the code work suddenly after several times running.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7CcZ.png)

---

[image]

---

I was expecting a table which was copied of a pivot table and its blank lines are filtered out.

the code (error is on `Worksheet().Activate`):

```
Sub Makro8()
    '
    ' Makro8 Makro
    '
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Fahrzeug"
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=LEFT(RC[3],5)"
    Range("A2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A1015"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("A2:A1015").Select
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 973
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 966
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 953
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 679
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 255
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 70
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
    
    Dim pc As PivotCache
    Dim ptName As String
    
    Worksheets("Eingangsdaten").Activate
    
    Set pc = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
             SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
             SourceData:=Range("A1").CurrentRegion)
    
    Worksheets.Add
    
    Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=Range("A1"), TableName:="TPivot")
    
    With pt
        .PivotFields("OE (nutzend)").Orientation = xlRowField
        .PivotFields("Fahrzeug").Orientation = xlColumnField
        .PivotFields("Fahrzeug").Orientation = xlDataField
        
        With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("TPivot").PivotFields("OE (nutzend)")
            .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
        End With
    End With
    
    Range("A1:O11").Select
    Range("O11").Activate
    Selection.Copy
    Range("A23").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                           :=False, Transpose:=False
    Rows("24:24").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Rows("24:24").Cut Destination:=Rows("23:23")
    Range("P26").Select
    
    Rows("1:22").Select
    Range("A22").Activate
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Range("G52").Select
    End
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to the board.  Could you edit your question and paste the code as text rather than a photo please - the edit button is at the bottom of your question.  Also worth having a read of [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: Is there any other workbook opened when the error arises? Notice that line `Worksheets("Eingangsdaten").Activate` will be executed at the active  workbook. If the active one does not have any worksheet named `Eingangsdaten` it will raise an error. If your code and worksheet `Eingangsdaten` is allocated at the same workbook, try `Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Eingangsdaten").Activate`

Comment: There is not any other Workbook open and I ve tried "Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Eingangsdaten").Activate" but it still says an error somehow

Comment: Maybe any other events activate that may interfere? IS this code in personal macro workbook or where? Did you try with object `ActiveWorkbook`? Did you execute it step by step with F8 to see the exact moment it fails and why?